# Create dataframe column based on the progression values of another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've the following dataframe:

```
     car_id  time(seconds)   is_charging  
1      1         65              1
2      1         70              1
3      1         67              1
4      1         71              1
5      1         120             0
6      1         124             0 
7      1         117             0
8      1         80              1
9      1         74              1
10     1         62              1
11     1         130             0
12     1         124             0
```

I want to create new column to enumerate the charging and discharging periods of the 'is_charging' column so later on i can groupby that new column and compute means, max, min values, etc,  of each period.

The resulting dataframe should be like this:

```
     car_id  time(seconds)   is_charging  periods_id
1      1         65              1            1
2      1         70              1            1
3      1         67              1            1
4      1         71              1            1
5      1         120             0            2
6      1         124             0            2
7      1         117             0            2
8      1         80              1            3
9      1         74              1            3
10     1         62              1            3
11     1         130             0            4
12     1         124             0            4
```

I've done this using for statment, like this:

```py
df['periods_ids] = 0

period_id = 1
previous_charging_state = df.at[0,'is_charging']

def computePeriodIDs():
    for ind in df.index:
        if df.at[index, 'is_charging'] != previous_charging_state:
            previous_charging_state  = df.at[index, 'is_charging']
            period_id  = period_id + 1
            df.at[index, 'periods_id'] = period_id
        else:
            df.at[index, 'periods_id'] = period_id
```

This is way too slow for the amount of rows that i have. I'm trying to use a vectorize function, especially the apply() one but due to my lack of understanding i haven't had much success and i can not find a similar problem online.

Can someone help me optimize this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.is_charging.diff().ne(0).cumsum()

Out[115]:
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    4
12    4
Name: is_charging, dtype: int32
```

Comment: works like a charm, but since i didn't know the function ne() even exists, i'm now trying to figure the logic

Comment: @RubenAlves: it also happens to me. From time to time, I am stumbled upon new methods and logics on SO which I have never heard before. I am still learning everyday. This logic is the classic one to create groupID. Let me know if you need any pointer.

Comment: I got it Andy, i tested step by step, checked the documentation and figure it out, thx for the quick answer :)